# Outlook addin commands fail on Windows Desktop client

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have created an addin for outlook that works as expected on Web, Windows and MacOS. But recently i have introduced Controls such as TaskPane Menu Buttons, Which on click invoke a function.

**In Manifest.xml**

```
              <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeFunctionButton">
               <Label resid="funcComposeButtonLabel" />
                <Supertip>
                  <Title resid="funcComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                  <Description resid="funcComposeSuperTipDescription" />
                </Supertip>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="InfoIcon.16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="InfoIcon.32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="InfoIcon.80x80" />
                </Icon>
                <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                  <FunctionName>addBccToComposeEmail</FunctionName>
                </Action>
              </Control>
```

In **Commands.js**

```
function addBccToComposeEmail(event) {
 Office.context.mailbox.item.bcc.setAsync(['test.test@test.com']);
 event.completed();
}
```

This works as expected on MacOS and Web, but shows a loader message in Windows desktop client which never stops.

[Spinning loader image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaIo9.png)

Kindly let me know what the issue might be ?

@Outlook Team pls help here.
@Office JS team, Can u kindly respond to this question ?

Comment: Have you tried to wait for the bcc.setAsync callback before calling event.completed?  If so, was the recipient set?

Comment: What version of Outlook Win32 are you testing this against? When this happens it usually means that either your HTML file is not reachable from win32, or there is an error in the JS. You can check if the file is obtained via fiddler. This is doubtful though, as it is being reached by the other clients. On older versions of Outlook Win32, you may be loading in IE instead of Edge. If so, there could be a JS error in your file that is incompatible with IE. (often arrow functions). See: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-edge-webview-for-office-add-ins/

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, As u have mentioned, The Edge devtools was perfect. Thanks for pointing that one, I was using F12/IEChooser.exe and the addin was not getting listed there. But it works now.  
One, important point is, I am still unable to debug, my commands.html. Is there any way to do that as mentioned in - [Sideloading and Debugging Outlook Add-ins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qD6eTKjg4fE&t=1s), Explained MSFT developer - Courtney Owen.

Comment: Would it be possible to see the whole manifest? Also, were you able to update your code with the suggestion in my first comment? If so, can you share the updated code? As for the debugging it is available for Office versions above 16.0.13729.20000 and for Yo Office project of type Office-Addin-Taskpane for TypeScript. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/debug-autolaunch) documentation for details.